# How to execute a shutdown with timer and screensaver command in a script

Tags: command-line, scripts, shutdown, screensaver

I made this script when executed will shutdown my system (after some time) and should enable a screensaver.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo shutdown -h +30
gnome-screensaver-command -a
```

There are mainly two problems in this script.

1. It asks for password (which I don't want)
2. After executing `sudo shutdown -h +30` its not running `gnome-screensaver-command -a`

that is, it activates shutdown but not the screensaver

How to solve these problem?

Comment: You can set a scrip to be started without password in /etc/sudoers.

Comment: @Pilot6 That is a security risk if you store the script in an unprotected location. Anything can happen if someone has access to edit the script.

Comment: True, but you can store it, e.g at /usr/bin

Comment: What about `sudo visudo` and on the file that opens up put this line `user ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown` where `user` is your username?

Comment: @Helio see terdons answer :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Ok, that's it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution to problem 1 and 2:

1. You need to edit your `/etc/sudoers` (`sudo visudo`) file to add the relevant entry to grant the passwordless `sudo` permission for the user to run this script (not the `shutdown` command) :

   ```
   foo spamegg = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh
   ```

   Here `foo` is the username, `spamegg` is the hostname, replace the `/path/to/script.sh` accordingly. Now run the command as (make the script executable):

   ```
   sudo /path/to/script.sh
   ```

   **Note that the `gnome-screensaver-command -a` command will also run as `root`**, if you don't want that you need to grant the permission for passwordless `sudo shutdown` command for the user:

   ```
   foo spamegg = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
   ```
2. The second problem is due to the fact that in your current script the `gnome-screensaver-command -a` will only run after the completion of `shutdown` command. As the `shutdown` command will actually be executed after 30 minutes, hence its in a blocking state. To solve this you can put the `shutdown` command in the background :

   ```
   shutdown -h +30 &
   gnome-screensaver-command -a
   ```

In a nutshell, you can make the script as following :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
shutdown -h +30 &
gnome-screensaver-command -a
```

Run it as :

```
sudo /path/to/script.sh
```

**Before using `sudo`, store the script in a secure place, it must only be accessible to you and you must be sure of the contents of the script.**

Comment: Note that adding the script to the sudoers file is a security risk unless you store it on a "secure" location. If anyone has access to edit the script, anything can happen. In an "unprotected" location quite easy.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yeah i probably should have mentioned that....adding..

Answer (score 2):

When you have two commands on two separate lines of a shell script, the second will only run when the first has finished. To avoid this, you need to add a `&` to the end of the first command to have it run in the background:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo shutdown -h +30 &
gnome-screensaver-command -a
```

As for not asking for the password, you'll need to tell `sudo` that your user has the right to run `/sbin/shutdown` with no password. Run `sudo visudo` and add this line to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
eka  ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/shutdown
```

Change `eka` to whatever your username is. Save the file and you will now be able to run `sudo shutdown` without being prompted for a password.